# Having 3 distinct values in a column and replacing them into 0/1s in pandas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have the following dataframe:

```
d = {'col1':['a','b','c','b','a','c','c','c'],'col2':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

I wonder how can I change `'a'` to `1`, `'b'` to `0` and 50% of `'c'` to `1` and 50% of the rest to 0 in `col1` at **random**?

So `col1` may look like this `[1,0,1,0,1,0,0,1]`

Comment: You may have to create a `function` on your own to do this specific job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compare values by `c` for mask by [`Series.eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.eq.html), then use [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) for set values by dictionary and last set 50% of values by [`Series.sample`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.sample.html) only filtered values:

```
m = df['col1'].eq('c')
df['col1'] = df['col1'].map({'a':1, 'b':0, 'c':0})

df.loc[df[m].sample(frac = 0.5).index, 'col1'] = 1
```

Or you can filter values and add `False` values by [`Series.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.reindex.html) for mask with size like original `DataFrame`:

```
m = df['col1'].eq('c')
df['col1'] = df['col1'].map({'a':1, 'b':0, 'c':0})

mask = m[m].sample(frac = 0.5).reindex(df.index, fill_value=False)
df.loc[mask, 'col1'] = 1
print (df)
   col1  col2
0     1     1
1     0     2
2     1     3
3     0     4
4     1     5
5     1     6
6     0     7
7     0     8
```

Numpy solution with [`numpy.random.choice`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc//numpy-1.10.4/reference/generated/numpy.random.choice.html):

```
m = df['col1'].eq('c')
df['col1'] = df['col1'].map({'a':1, 'b':0, 'c':0})

df.loc[m, 'col1'] = np.random.choice([0,1], p=[0.5, 0.5], size=m.sum())
```

Comment: The second method was my choice simply because the random choice distributes 50-50 equally.